# condition statements involving coordinates, Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, if-statement, coordinates, conditional-statements

I have been having no end of trouble with Flash CS3 lately. I really need some help clearing the scripting.

I've been trying to make a code in actionscript that will set a function to `true` if an object is moved to a specific part of the screen. The confusing thing is making the rule apply to when it's between a specific four coordinates (in this case, 165 and
231 as the X coordinates, and 295 and 330 as the y coordinates; "honey" is the instance name of the symbol).

The last time I asked for help, I was given this code:

```
bool IsBetweenInclusive(int value, int lower, int upper)
{
    return value >= lower 
        && value <= upper;
}
```

However, when I tried to turn it into a condition statement, it wouldn't work. I really need help, and will really appreciate assistance.

Comment: That code is not ActionScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Whether a point is within a rectangular bounds.
     *
     * @param x         Point x-coordinate to be tested.
     * @param y         Point y-coordinate to be tested.
     * @param bounds    Rectangle boundary to be tested against.
     * @return          True if point is within bounds.
     */
    public static function withinBounds(x:Number, y:Number, bounds:Rectangle):Boolean
    {
        if ((x > bounds.x) &&
            (x < bounds.x + bounds.width) &&
            (y > bounds.y) &&
            (y < bounds.y + bounds.height))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [rectangle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html), it already has a method for that. Assuming you have an the upper left point `x1,y1` and the bottom right point `x2,y2` and the point `x,y` you want to check:

```
var area = new Rectangle (x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);

if( area.contains(x,y) ) { /* ... */ }
```

There's also [containsRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html#containsRect%28%29) if you need to check if an object is completely in the given area.